# HTTP could not register URL http://+:10001/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace

Tags: wcf, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I just upgraded from Windows 7/VS2010 to a clean install of Windows 8/VS2012.
I'm logging onto a domain user (domain admin) and have started seeing this error when launching some of my wcf services from VS2012:

> HTTP could not register URL `http://+:10001/`. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace

I've never experienced this before on Windows 7 and I'm a little perplexed why I'm seeing this now in Windows 8 (domain admin, user access control turned off).
With some research I found out that this error arises due to the VS process not running with admin rights and non admins apparently can't listen on TCP ports, however, I don't quite follow why VS wouldn't run as admin as the user I'm logging in to is a domain admin?

Comment: Visual Studio Run as Admin worked for me!!!

Answer (score 10):

You must execute something like this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:10001/YourUri/ user=\Everyone
```

or

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:10001/YourUri/ user=DOMAIN\user
```

Something is mentioned in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) or google for "netsh http add urlacl"

AFAIK since Vista processes do not run with elevated privileges even if launched by Admin account. That is the whole point behind UAC.
However after you run `netsh` command you will not need anything like that anyway.

Comment: Thanks that works - my questions was more directed towards what changed between Windows 7 and Windows 8? In windows 7, with UAC turned off, applications were running with elevated permission, in windows 8, with UAC turned off, this seems to be no longer the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can change Account window to administrator in control panel, it's have all permission to run url.

Comment: I'm a local administrator and I still get the error. What OS are you on? I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure,  you run both the VS and Command prompt as Administrator. 
Execute the command on Command Prompt

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:10001 user=<your_userid>
```

Open VS as Administrator